# CursorAdapter bindView give me a unique view for all the row

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

CursorAdapter.bindView give me a unic view for all the row.

On the first display of my list, I got issue with the image loaded in my imageView.
Some image are not loaded in the good row. 
My investigation point out that bindView pass me the same imageView for all the row. So my asynTask will load the image in the wrong row.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return vi.inflate(R.layout.cursor_adapter_item, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cursor_adapter_item_image);
        d("bindView.cursor.getPosition() : " + cursor.getPosition());
        d("bindView imageView : " + imageView.toString());

        // logic to create/get/set the (remote) image. use local drawable or asyntask and a ref of imageview to load the image.
    }
```

logcat extract of the FIRST paint/show of the list. Notice that all the imageView got the same ref.

```
04-09 10:58:57.520 E/TESTING (10211): MyCursorAdapter : notifyDataSetChanged
04-09 10:58:57.532 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 0
04-09 10:58:57.532 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.536 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 0
04-09 10:58:57.536 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.536 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.551 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 1
04-09 10:58:57.551 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.551 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.614 D/dalvikvm(10211): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11059K, 58% free 10701K/25415K, paused 58ms, total 59ms
04-09 10:58:57.614 W/SQLiteConnectionPool(10211): A SQLiteConnection object for database leaked [....]
04-09 10:58:57.684 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 2
04-09 10:58:57.684 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.684 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.762 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 3
04-09 10:58:57.762 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.762 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.766 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 4
04-09 10:58:57.766 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.766 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.770 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 5
04-09 10:58:57.770 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.770 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.778 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 6
04-09 10:58:57.778 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.778 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.786 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 0
04-09 10:58:57.786 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 10:58:57.786 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
04-09 10:58:57.797 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 1
04-09 10:58:57.797 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@422778d0
04-09 10:58:57.797 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 1
04-09 10:58:57.797 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@422778d0
04-09 10:58:57.797 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@41dce368
04-09 10:58:57.844 D/dalvikvm(10211): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 928K, 55% free 11681K/25415K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
04-09 10:58:57.914 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 2
04-09 10:58:57.914 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@4203edb8
04-09 10:58:57.914 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 2
04-09 10:58:57.914 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@4203edb8
04-09 10:58:57.914 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@42012a50
04-09 10:58:57.926 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 3
04-09 10:58:57.926 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@423076e8
04-09 10:58:57.926 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 3
04-09 10:58:57.930 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@423076e8
04-09 10:58:57.930 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4232e5d8
04-09 10:58:57.942 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 4
04-09 10:58:57.942 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@423fd400
04-09 10:58:57.942 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 4
04-09 10:58:57.942 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@423fd400
04-09 10:58:57.942 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4234d8b0
04-09 10:58:57.953 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 5
04-09 10:58:57.953 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42335f50
04-09 10:58:57.957 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 5
04-09 10:58:57.957 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42335f50
04-09 10:58:57.957 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423589b8
04-09 10:58:57.969 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 6
04-09 10:58:57.969 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@422dd560
04-09 10:58:57.973 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 6
04-09 10:58:57.973 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@422dd560
04-09 10:58:57.973 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423d9d58
04-09 10:58:58.168 E/DatabaseUtils( 6622): Writing exception to parcel
04-09 10:58:58.168 E/DatabaseUtils( 6622): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column orientation [...]
04-09 10:58:58.496 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView.cursor.getPosition() : 0
04-09 10:58:58.496 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]newView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.496 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 0
04-09 10:58:58.508 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.508 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 10:58:58.512 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 1
04-09 10:58:58.512 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.516 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 10:58:58.602 D/dalvikvm(10211): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2089K, 53% free 11981K/25415K, paused 73ms, total 79ms
04-09 10:58:58.700 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 2
04-09 10:58:58.700 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.700 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 10:58:58.703 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 3
04-09 10:58:58.703 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.703 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 10:58:58.711 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 4
04-09 10:58:58.711 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.711 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 10:58:58.715 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 5
04-09 10:58:58.715 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.715 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 10:58:58.719 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 6
04-09 10:58:58.719 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 10:58:58.723 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
```

after 1st paint. logcat extract after scrolling Scroll down one item, then up one item.  notice that the imageView got different ref and that the image are displayed on the good row.

```
04-09 11:05:10.192 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 7
04-09 11:05:10.192 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@42270aa8
04-09 11:05:10.192 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@4236e480
04-09 11:05:10.657 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView.cursor.getPosition() : 0
04-09 11:05:10.657 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView view : android.widget.LinearLayout@420171f0
04-09 11:05:10.657 E/TESTING (10211): [MyCursorAdapter]bindView imageView : android.widget.ImageView@423472d8
```

EDIT: add clear questions

- Is this behavior normal ?
- What do you suggest to reach my goal / fix my code ?

EDIT2: more logcat

Comment: oh, do you need to extend a CursorAdapter? why not using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @pskink I do have more logic in the class. But, No, I do not have a special need for this class/way of doing thing.I am open to alternative.

Comment: so use SCA + ViewBinder

Comment: But, Why does CursorAdapter pass me the same view every time ?

Comment: Log.d what you return in newView

Comment: newView is only called once before the first batch of bindView. May this be related to onMesure of the listView ?

Comment: once??? if you have for example 5 visible items it should be called 5 times

Comment: which is why I came to SO to ask about it! ;-) Note that it is called N time, but later on (after i start to download the images)

Comment: so how many items can you see in your ListView ?

Comment: I can see between 6-8 item at a time on my list view

Comment: so why you say newView is called once?

Comment: Because it is called only once! at 57.532. Then the first batch of bindView is called for each item, then from 57.797 on the newView/bindView is called once per item. (see logcat). As I stated in my question, this only happend "on first display"